# Let top windows have focus after workspace switch

Tags: gnome3

I have set keyboard shortcuts for my workspaces and want to use the (only) application on that workspace directly after switching the workspace, e.g. type into the terminal without having to give it focus with a mouse click. Unfortunately, ofttimes windows on other monitors get focus instead (probably depending on which window had focus last). Is there a way to automatically let the top window on a workspace get focus after switching to it?

To prevent falling into the [XY Problem:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What I really want is to switch to windows via keyboard shortcuts. Custom shortcuts in combination with [`xdotool`](https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Xdotool) should do the job, but `xdotool`doesn't work properly under wayland. I though using different workspaces would be a solution, but now I'm stuck with the above focus problem.

Comment: Would some kind of 'focus follows mouse' help you when switching to a new work space? Gnome3 can be extended with that functionality.

Comment: @datUser: Unfortunately, no. If the mouse stays on one of the the other displays (which don't switch workspaces), the focus will still to be on the wrong window.